# BBDB/OrgMode Workflow to store additional information

Tags: org-mode

What is the best strategy to establish links and reverse links to my contacts stored in BBDB?

My Outline is similar to this:

```
* Projects
** a
** b
-> link to contact?
** c
* Notes
** 2014-04-02 Meeting with Contact A
-> link to contact?
```

How can I create a workflow so that all references to this contact are shown, once I open this contact in BBDB?

Currently I use a "hack" where I manually enter links to the entries in the "Notes" field of that entry. But as it is not possible to inclide org-mode outlines in the "Notes" filed, it is an appalling list unusable links.